# Socket stays "waiting for reading" but nothing is read

Tags: sockets, python-3.8, python-sockets

I have a system that uses Python to control a pan/tilt head from Flir.
The p/t is listening to commands on a raw TCP socket.

Below is the relevant code for the creation of the socket (additional comments for clarity, hopefully this has all required code...).

```py
import socket
import select

def connect(self) -> None:
     """Set up socket connection."""
     try:
         self.socket = socket.create_connection((self.ip, self.port), self.timeout)
     except (socket.timeout, OSError):
         msg = f'Problem setting up socket for pan/tilt head ({self.ip}:{self.port})'
         raise PTHeadConnectionError(msg)
     else:
         self._set_socket_options()
         self._empty_rcv_socket()
         self.log.debug('Socket set up.')

def _set_socket_options(self) -> None:
    self.socket.settimeout(3)  # might not be needed
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY,
                           1)  # disable Nagle's algorithm (recommended by hardware mfg)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)  # send keepalive packets
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)  # Start sending packets after 1s
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 1)  # Send packet every 1s

def _empty_rx_buffer(self) -> None:
    read_data = ''  # to help debug
    while True:
        read, __, __ = select.select([self.socket], [], [], 0)
        if len(read) == 0:
            break
        self.log.debug('before self.socket.recv(1)')  # to help debug
        read_data += self.socket.recv(1).decode()  # record what's in the buffer to help troubleshoot
        self.log.debug(f'after self.socket.recv(1).decode() [{read_data}]')  # to help debug
```

The issue I'm having -and completely fail to understand- is in the `_empty_rx_buffer` method. I call it each time before issuing a command to make sure there aren't any packets from the p/t head that might belong to a previous command.

Calling the `_empty_rx_buffer` method works fine for thousands of commands, but every so often, my script will appear to hang. At that point, I see thousands of lines like these in my logs:

```
109360  2023-06-14 17:05:18.853 DEBUG   d48e_connections._empty_rcv_socket(146) before self.socket.recv(1).decode()
109361  2023-06-14 17:05:18.882 DEBUG   d48e_connections._empty_rcv_socket(148) after self.socket.recv(1).decode() []
109362  2023-06-14 17:05:18.921 DEBUG   d48e_connections._empty_rcv_socket(146) before self.socket.recv(1).decode()
109363  2023-06-14 17:05:18.949 DEBUG   d48e_connections._empty_rcv_socket(148) after self.socket.recv(1).decode() []
```

It took me a while to narrow the issue down to this point, but I'm stuck. If I understand correctly, the three first lines in the while loop should break out of the class method if there is nothing waiting anymore. However, nothing seems to be in the buffer and reading from it doesn't change its status.

I don't have much confidence in the network implementation on the p/t head. I've used multiple of these heads, and the connection would drop on all of them once in while. Still, I think I should be able to catch and handle that in code *as long as my code does the right thing*.

I don't just want to avoid the issue but also understand what is happening. What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: *Get rid of* the `_empty_rx_buffer ()` method, and make sure you consume all messages completely in the place that consumes them. Your `_empty_rx_buffer ()` is just a crutch for bad codiing elsewhere. Not surprising it doesn't work. If you can identify the end of the message in `_empty_rx_buffer ()`, why can't you identify it elsewhere?

Comment: What I'm doing is making sure the buffer is empty, send a command and then read the response until the message delimiter. However, in between commands, the head might send additional messages when it experiences errors. Either I close the socket after each command (and loose any possible feedback in between commands), or keep the socket open and need to make sure it's empty before sending a new command. In any case, I'd like to understand what is happening in the case described above. Likely I'm misunderstanding something, and I don't just want to "avoid the issue" but understand...

Comment: Nevertheless you should not have a method wose purpose is to empty the buffer. You should have a method or methods that *parse* every *message* that is still in the buffer, and process them appropriately. In fact this should be happening continuously if the peer can send unsolicited messages. Don't skimp on protocol implementation. Skipping to the next EOT is not sufficient.

Comment: I can live with that idea, but then the same thing would happen in another method. Here I'm clearing out the buffer, reading out one byte at a time. If I'd do that in a method where I actually process the received data, I'd still have this question popping up...

Comment: No you won't. Your problem is that you are emptying the buffer by reading it to end of stream,or maybe a timeout, instead of parsing it for messages, and it is surely *here* that you are blocking. So you are consuming wanted messages. If you substitute correct parsing for reading to end of stream you cannot possibly have this problem.

Comment: Then I misunderstood. I thought the `read, __, __ = select.select([self.socket], [], [], 0)` line would show you that there was data ready for reading, and then you'd use `self.socket.recv(1)` to read from the buffer. If that is the case, I would use the exact same construct in my read method... Maybe I'm basing myself to much on PIC microcontrollers and the pySerial library...

Comment: Ah no, there I haven't used `read, _, _ = select.select([self.socket],[],[],0)` but just read everything from the buffer until I get a message postamble or it times out...